# Insert a bool value into MySQL depending on selected ComboBox

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this combo-box in winforms:

[image]

I have added values like so...

[image]

[image]

On selected value I'd like to insert a bool value in MySQL (`Yes` for `True` - `No` for `False`)

**Question:**

What is the correct way of inserting a bool value depending on selected value of combobox?

**Current Code**

```
    public void UpdateData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
            {
                string updateQuery = "INSERT INTO customer_complaints_actions " +
                    "(complaint_id,value " +
                    "VALUES " +
                    "(@complaint_id, @value)";

                using(var connect = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
                {
                    using(var cmd = new MySqlCommand(updateQuery, connect))
                    {
                        connect.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@complaint_id", Convert.ToInt32(ComplaintsDataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value.SelectedItem); // Need to alter
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.ToString()}", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a conditional expression when adding the data to the query:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value.SelectedItem == "Yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a conditional expression in the `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO customer_complaints_actions (complaint_id,value)
VALUES (@complaint_id, @value = 'Yes')
```

In MySLQ, condition `@value = 'Yes'` evaluates as `1` if the condition is true, else `0`.